# Simple Tic-Tac_Toe Game Pygame

Tags: python, pygame, python-3.4

I am writing a simple tic-tac-toe game in pygame and cannot find the answer I need. I want an "X" to  appear when the mouse is clicked within a certain coordinate plane. The code I have now will only display an X when the mouse button is held down. Thanks

```
import pygame
import sys

red = (255,0,0)
green = (0,255,0)
blue = (0,0,255)
darkBlue = (0,0,128)
white = (255,255,255)
black = (0,0,0)
pink = (255,200,200)

#iconChoice = input("Would you like to be X's or O's?(X/O)?:")

iconChoice = "X"

# initialize game engine
pygame.init()
pygame.font.init()
font = pygame.font.SysFont("Century Schoolbook",12)
# set screen width/height and caption
size = [500,500]
screen = pygame.display.set_mode(size)
pygame.display.set_caption('My Game')
# initialize clock. used later in the loop.
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

# Loop until the user clicks close button
done = False
while done == False:
    # write event handlers here
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            done = True
    # write game logic here

    sys_font = pygame.font.SysFont("None",60)
    rendered = sys_font.render(iconChoice, 0, black)
    mousexpos, mouseypos = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
    pygame.event.get()

    '''                
    elif pygame.mouse.get_pressed()[0] == True and mousexpos > 166 and mousexpos < 322 and  mouseypos < 156:
        print("2")

    elif pygame.mouse.get_pressed()[0] == True and mousexpos > 332 and  mouseypos < 156:
        print("3")
        done = True

    elif pygame.mouse.get_pressed()[0] == True and mousexpos < 156 and  mouseypos > 166 and mouseypos < 322:
        print("4")
        done= True

    elif pygame.mouse.get_pressed()[0] == True and mousexpos > 166 and mousexpos < 322 and  mouseypos > 166 and mouseypos < 322:
        print("5")
        done= True

    elif pygame.mouse.get_pressed()[0] == True and mousexpos > 332 and  mouseypos > 166 and mouseypos < 322:
        print("6")
        done = True

    elif pygame.mouse.get_pressed()[0] == True and mousexpos < 156 and  mouseypos > 332:
        print("7")
        done= True

    elif pygame.mouse.get_pressed()[0] == True and mousexpos > 166 and mousexpos < 322 and  mouseypos > 332:
        print("8")
        done= True

    elif pygame.mouse.get_pressed()[0] == True and mousexpos > 332 and  mouseypos > 332:
        print("9")
        done = True

    '''

    # clear the screen before drawing
    screen.fill((255, 255, 255))


    # draw
    pygame.draw.rect(screen, black, (10,156,480,15), 0)
    pygame.draw.rect(screen, black, (10,322,480,15), 0)
    pygame.draw.rect(screen, black, (156,10,15,480), 0)
    pygame.draw.rect(screen, black, (322,10,15,480), 0)
    pygame.display.flip()

    if pygame.mouse.get_pressed()[0] == True and mousexpos < 156 and mouseypos < 156:
        print("1")
        screen.blit(rendered, (20,15))
        pygame.display.update(10,10,166,166)


    # display what’s drawn. this might change.
    pygame.display.update()

    # run at 20 fps
    clock.tick(20)

# close the window and quit    
pygame.quit()
```

Comment: Off the top of my head, it looks like you should store the value of pygame.mouse.get_pressed() in a variable, and use the variable for your subsequent evaluations.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Wouldn't it be the same thing because the variable would only be true when the key is being mouse button is being pressed down?

Answer (score 1):

Here is what you will need:
Mouse position:

```
mouse_pos = mouse.get_pos()
```

And a rect:

```
rect1 = Rect(top_left_corner_x, top_left_corner_y, width, height)
```

Then you check if the mouse is clicked in this rect:

```
if event.type == MOUSEBUTTONDOWN and rect1.collidepoint(mouse_pos):
    #draw X
```

You can put this in your event loop or outside(but preferably inside).

Comment: Thank you for your response but when I edited my code, the outcome was the same. The X only appeared when the mouse was held down

Comment: Try and put this in your event loop. That should do the trick.